# Select the missing word in the sentence from the possible options

Tags: machine-learning, nlp

I have a sentence with a missing word.

```
"I want to buy a ___ to drive it."
```

And I have answer options that may be here.

```
["car", "cat", "can"]
```

I need to choose the most suitable word. I wanted to do it with BERT, but there is no way to specify which words can be.

Answer (score 0):

You can restrict BERT to a word list. In fact, I made a library which does this: [FitBert](https://github.com/Qordobacode/fitbert).

```py
from fitbert import FitBert


fb = FitBert()

masked_string = "I want to buy a ***mask*** to drive it."
options = ["car", "cat", "can"]

ranked_options = fb.rank(masked_string, options=options)
assert ranked_options[0] == "car"
```